# to show this a complete

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $E=\{x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n_{+}:\sum x_i=1\}$, and $E^{o}=\{x\in E : x_i>0 \forall i\}$, define 
$d(x,y)=\max\limits_{i} \ln\frac{x_i}{y_i}-\min\limits_{j} \ln\frac{x_j}{y_j}\forall x, y\in E^o$. Could any one tell me $(E^o, d)$ is complete metric space or not? I have not seen such metric before. Thanks for helping.

I feel like I can write  $e^{d(x,y)}=\frac{\max\limits_{i}\frac{x_i}{y_i}}{{\min\limits_{j}\frac{x_j}{y_j}}}$

Comment: Yes and no, this metric is known as Hilbert's metric and it's a metric on the rays of the cone, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_metric. The metric topology on a slice of the cone coincides with the norm topology on the interior of the cone, so the metric space is complete if and only if the normed space is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(E^o, d)$ is complete. To see this, consider the function

$$\phi : E^o \rightarrow \mathbb R^n, \text { with } \phi((x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)):=(\ln x_1,\ln x_2,\ldots,\ln x_n).$$

Assume for $x,y \in E^o$ that $d(x,y)=\delta$. Note that due to the sum condition on elements of $E$, in your distance definition the term $\max\limits_{i} \ln\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ will always be non-negative and the term $\min\limits_{j} \ln\frac{x_j}{y_j}$ will always be non-positive. That means

\begin{align*}
    \left\lvert\max\limits_{i} \ln\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\rvert \le \delta
    \text{ and } \left\lvert\min\limits_{j} \ln\frac{x_j}{y_j}\right\rvert \le \delta
\end{align*}

But that means that for any index $k$, if $x_k \ge y_k$, then

$$ 0 \le \ln x_k- \ln y_k = \ln \frac{x_k}{y_k} \le \max\limits_{i} \ln\frac{x_i}{y_i} \le \delta$$

and hence

$$\lvert \ln x_k- \ln y_k \rvert \le \delta.$$

On the other hand, if $x_k < y_k$, then

$$ 0 > \ln x_k- \ln y_k = \ln \frac{x_k}{y_k} \ge \min\limits_{j} \ln\frac{x_j}{y_j} \ge -\delta$$

and hence again.

$$\lvert \ln x_k- \ln y_k \rvert \le \delta.$$

That means

$$\lVert \phi(x,y) \rVert_\infty \le \delta.$$

So if you have a Cauchy sequence $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\ldots$ in $(E^o, d)$, then $\phi(x^{(1)}),\phi(x^{(2)}), \ldots$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb R^n,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$.

Since the latter space is complete, that sequence $\phi(x^{(1)}),\phi(x^{(2)}), \ldots$ converges to a limit $r=(r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_n)$.

Define

$$\psi: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R \text{ as } \psi((x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)) :=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}$$

By the sum condition on $E$, we find that

$$\forall x \in E^o: \psi(\phi(x))=1.$$

So we have in particular $\forall i=1,2,\ldots: \psi(\phi(x^{(i)}))=1$. Now $\psi$ is a continuous function (using $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ in the domain). Since we know that $\lim_{i \to \infty} \phi(x^{(i)}) = r$ in $(\mathbb R^n,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$, we can conclude that $\psi(r)=1.$

Now set $s=(e^{r_1},e^{r_2},\ldots,e^{r_n})$. By what we just proved, we know that $s \in E^o$.

It remains to show that our original Cauchy sequence $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\ldots$ converges to $s$. Be the definition of $\phi$ and $r$, we have componentwise convergence for the logarithms:

$$\forall k=1,2,\ldots,n: \lim_{i \to \infty} \ln x^{(i)}_k = r_k.$$

Again, by $e^x$ being a continuous function, we can conclude

$$\forall k=1,2,\ldots,n: \lim_{i \to \infty} x^{(i)}_k = e^{r_k}=s_k.$$

So the considered Cauchy sequence converges componentwise to $s$.

That means for a given $\epsilon > 0$ there is for each index $k$ a number $N_k$ such that 
$$\forall i > N_k: \lvert x^{(i)}_k - s_k \rvert < \min (s_ke^{\frac{\epsilon}2}-s_k, s_k - s_ke^{\frac{-\epsilon}2}) \Rightarrow e^{\frac{-\epsilon}2} < \frac{x^{(i)}_k}{s_k} < e^{\frac{\epsilon}2}$$

From that we get

$$ \forall i > N_k: -\frac{\epsilon}2 < \ln \frac{x^{(i)}_k}{s_k} < \frac{\epsilon}2$$

Combining all the componentwise results we get

$$ \forall k,\, \forall i > \max(N_1,\ldots,N_n): -\frac{\epsilon}2 < \ln \frac{x^{(i)}_k}{s_k} < \frac{\epsilon}2$$

This means

$$ \forall i > \max(N_1,\ldots,N_n): \max\limits_{k}\ln \frac{x^{(i)}_k}{s_k} < \frac{\epsilon}2$$

and

$$ \forall i > \max(N_1,\ldots,N_n): \min\limits_{k}\ln \frac{x^{(i)}_k}{s_k} > -\frac{\epsilon}2$$

and finally

$$\forall i > \max(N_1,\ldots,N_n): d(x^{(i)}, s) < \epsilon.$$

This concludes the prof, as $s$ has been established as the limit of the Cauchy series $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\ldots$ in $(E^o, d)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, What did you mean by  ''By the sum condition on $E$''?

Comment: The $\sum x_i=1$ part in the definition of $E$.